# How to call Shell Execute using Qt connect function?

Tags: c++, qt

I have following function call:

```
sparseAct =new QAction(QIcon(":Icons/icons/sparse.jpg"),tr("Sparse Reconstruction"),this);

connect(sparseAct, SIGNAL(triggered()),this, SLOT(sparsereconstruction()));
```

and

```
void UAVgeoreferencer::sparsereconstruction(){

ShellExecute(NULL, L"open", L"C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe", L"/C C:\\Images\\sparseRecon64.bat", L"C:\\Images\\", SW_SHOWNORMAL);

}
```

When I do this I get error like:

> uavgeoreferencer.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol
>   __imp_ShellExecuteW referenced in function "private: void __cdecl UAVgeoreferencer::sparsereconstruction(void)"
>   (?sparsereconstruction@UAVgeoreferencer@@AEAAXXZ)

Can anyone tell me what is the problem and how can I solve it??

Comment: I think you should link your program against `Shell32.lib` library too in order to use its `ShellExecute` function, or you need to use `QProcess` to execute the `sparseRecon64.bat` script.

Comment: Seems like a bit of an XY problem.  I'd use QProcess for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QProcess` for this purpose since it inherits `QObject` and `QIODevice`, you have everything you need to pass data between other Qt objects you might be using but you don't have to. You can always create your own objects that inherit from `QObject` and then implement signals and slots mechanism but `QProcess` will make life easier as it has already everything one might possibly need for shell access. However, the problem you are facing is related to the linker and has nothing to do with Signals and Slots mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have forgotten to link [required windows library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to your project. Try adding this to your `.pro` file:

```
LIBS *= Shell32.lib
```